# Autofocus on the textbox in html razor code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razor-2

I want the cursor to be focused on the textbox when I load the page. I tried by adding autofocus="" but I couldn't find any difference in that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    m => m.UserName, 
    "@xyz.com", 
    new { @class = "form-control input-lg", @id = "username"})
```

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, "@xyz.com", new { @class = "form-control input-lg", @id = "username", autofocus = "autofocus" })`, but `autofocus = ""` should also work

Comment: Works fine for me. Whats the 2nd parameter you have shown here? It does not look like a format string!

Comment: You realize the `autofocus` attribute is not supported in IE9 and earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with jquery, you can try using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#username").focus();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use plain java script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("username").focus();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `autofocus` attribute isn't implemented in all browsers. It's a good subset of browsers with most newer browsers having it, but not all.  It is likely you were using a browser that does not support the `autofocus` attribute.  [Dive into HTML 5 has a good listing of the browser support.](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#autofocus)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#username").focus();
       });       
    }); </script>
```